# Informatica Reg_extract not working

Tags: regex, informatica

I have string with following samples, and I need to slit by slash. Maximum number of 4 slashes, and minimum of 0 slash can be given. Also, there can be spaces in middle. Can just reg_extract will work?

Example:
helloworld
hello world
helloworld/canyouhearme
hello world/can you hear me/atall
hello world/can you hear me/atall/say
hellowworld/canyouhearme/atall/say

Answer (score 0):

You'll need 5 ports each with a split expression (and Lpad Rpad to remove padding) tailored to the section you are extracting

See following link where Nico explains same https://network.informatica.com/thread/16336